# Python: Writing a greater than and less than form

Tags: python

So I am writing a code about with an elif statements like if a student get a score below 60, they will get an F. if they got a score atleast 60 but below 70, they will get a D. But reading the problem suddenly got me confuse on how to use the less than and greater than again;-; i already tried to do it but i am not sure if i am correct. so here's the problem;

and below this, is my i-tried-to-do-it

Comment: try with `elif 80 <= score and score < 90`, ..

Answer (score 3):

How about this approach:

```
print('FFFFFFDCBAA'[score // 10])
```

In Python 3, `score // 10` will give you an integer index!
For example, `75 // 10 = 7`.

Comment: Fun, but not very adaptable, and hard to make sense of.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Why? Could be better than too many branching.

Comment: Nice, efficient but might be on the fence for newer users not sure about indices

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi I would always endeavor to answer the question wherein the OP learns where he is going wrong in the code HE has written. That helps him learn. Giving him some advanced code as an answer if if much more efficient makes him skip the learning curve. My 2 bits on your answer. :)

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi It's not very flexible when you have adapt it to finer or non-uniform grading, it works for this kind of example, but is not a good general approach to write a grading map.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to compare the score to constants, also mind the indentation:

```py
if score >= 90:
    print('A')
elif score >= 80:
    print('B')
elif score >= 70:
    print('C')
elif score >= 60:
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since an `elif` clause will only run if all previous `if` and `elif` are False, you don't have to check ranges. As long as you test from highest to lowest, its just

```
score = 77

if score >= 90:
    print("A")
elif score >= 80:
    print("B")
elif score >= 70:
    print("C")
elif score >= 60:
    print("D")
else:
    print("F")
```

If the `if` clauses seem repetitive, you could create a list of bounds and spin through them in a loop. But for this case, the if's will be a bit faster in execution.

```
grade_levels = ((90, "A"), (80, "B"), (70, "C"), (60, "D"))
def get_grade(score):
    for lower_bound, grade in grade_levels:
        if score >= lower_bound:
            return grade
    return "F"

print(get_grade(100))
print(get_grade(80))
print(get_grade(44))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dict` to map the lower bounds to each grade, then just iterate over that `dict` to find the grade:

```
def print_grade(score):
    """
    the keys in grades must be monotonically decreasing
    """
    grades = {
        90: 'A',
        80: 'B',
        70: 'C',
        60: 'D',
         0: 'F'
    }
    
    for k, v in grades.items():
        if score >= k:
            print(v)
            break
```

With this you can more easily replace the grade levels, without changing the actual logic below, providing a more clean separation between "algorithm" and "data". This can also be done using `tuple`s or `list`s. Such a separation can later allow you to pass `grades` as a parameter from outside the function, e.g. if you have another piece of code which calculates the grading map.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `80<=90` will always be true since you compare constant integers you should compare the variable.

```
 if score >=90:
    print('A')
elif score>=80:
    print('B')
elif score>=70:
    print('C')
elif score>=60:
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')
```

Comment: My bad, sorry, you cannot use `=<`, you should use `<=`

Comment: Doesn't work. A score of 7 is `<= 90` so you'd get a B. You want `>=` for all.

Comment: Invert the order of the if statements otherwise it always prints B

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You should add indentation or you will get an error.

```
marks = int(input("Enter Marks: "))
if marks>=90:
    print("A")
elif marks>80:
    print("B")
elif marks>70:
    print("C")
elif marks>60:
    print("D")
else:
    print("F")
```